# Need help understanding the geometry of a particular building structure

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I’m not primarily a geometer, so apologies if this question is worded poorly. I’ve been looking at asymptotic cones of connected semisimple Lie groups with at least one absolutely simple factor $S$ such that $\mathbb R$-rank$(S)\geq2$, which is discussed in [this paper by Kramer, Shelah, Tent, and Thomas](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306420). In my head, I’m usually just imagining $\SL_m(\mathbb R)$ for $m\geq3$, which they mention as a special case. In the paper, they showed that, depending on the Continuum Hypothesis, there is, up to homeomorphism, either a unique such asymptotic cone or $2^{\mathfrak c}$-many as you vary your choice of ultrafilter.

One thing that I’m trying to understand better is the actual geometry of these asymptotic cones. They mention that they have a building structure, which was proved in [this paper by Kramer and Tent](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209122). Interestingly, in the case of $\SL_2(\mathbb R)$, there’s still a building structure, but there’s a unique asymptotic cone depending on your choice of ultrafilter, regardless of the truth of CH. [This paper by Dyubina and Polterovich](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9904133), for instance, explains the geometry of the asymptotic cone of $\SL_2(\mathbb R)$, and that it’s a $2^{\aleph_0}$-universal $\mathbb R$-tree (which was proven by Gromov). For a cardinal $\mu$, they explain that a $\mu$-universal $\mathbb R$-tree is an $\mathbb R$-tree $T$ such that, for every point $t\in T$, $T\smallsetminus t$ has $\mu$-many connected components (aka a *valency* of $\mu$), and any $\mathbb R$-tree with valency at most $\mu$ at every point can be embedded into this $\mathbb R$-tree.

Intuitively, I think of this as a copy of the real line, and at every point, I have continuum-many copies of the real line “branching” off, each of which has continuum-many branches at each of its points, ad infinitum.

I *expect* a similar sort of “branching” occurs in the geometry of asymptotic cones of $\SL_m(\mathbb R)$ when $m\geq3$, but because the apartments are now a dimension larger, it no longer makes sense to talk about branching at a point. I would *expect* that these branches occur at any set fixed by an action of the affine Weyl group on a given apartment (in my head, I imagine this as copies of $\mathbb R^2$ intersecting at all lines parallel to reflection lines through the origin).

**My vague question is this:** how can I better understand the geometry of the building structure from the KSTT paper so that I have a concrete way to look at these “branching” points? Because the way that my intuition is telling me the geometry should work out, I convince myself that there’s also only one asymptotic cone up to homeomorphism, regardless of which ultrafilter I’m using, and regardless of CH, which is false given KSTT. So somewhere my intuition is leading me astray, but I don't have enough background in geometry to make sense of these potential "branchings" rigorously.

Comment: For a first simpler higher-dimensional example: the asymptotic cone of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})^n$ is a product of $n$ real trees (each complete everywhere of continuum valency). If it can help figure out what "branching" should mean...